# Changing the x-axis data month to year in google visualization line chart

Tags: api, google-visualization, linechart

I just want to show only year not the date. How can i do that??

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Average Price');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date (2011,0,1), 278000], [new Date (2012,0,1), 283500], [new Date (2013,0,1), 303000],
    [new Date (2014,0,1), 327000]
  ]);


  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 320,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Average Sale Price'
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a date formatter : [Date Formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformatter)

If you want to have just the year in the tooltip, date formatter is the way to go:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'yyyy'});
formatter.format(data, 0)
```

If you want just the year for the axis, you need to format the axis in the options:

```
hAxis: {
  title: 'Time',
  format: 'yyyy'
}
```